# импорт в VS code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, импорт

Проблема общая и возникает у меня для любых python-файлов!

Есть два python-файла: в первом импортируется функция из второго. Работаю в Visual Studio Code.

При внесении изменений в первый файл и сохранении - это изменения игнорируются при повторном импорте во втором файле. Приходится перезапускать VS code чтобы импортировать измененную версию файла.

Можно ли как-то это исправить в настройках, чтобы все изменения сразу при сохранении были доступны для импорта?

Comment: `reload` не помогает? <https://docs-python.ru/standart-library/paket-importlib-python/funktsija-reload-modulja-importlib/>

Comment: Покажите для начала структуру проекта и свой launch.json файл :) пока не понятен корень проблемы :)

Comment: Спасибо, кажется, разобрался.
В самой VS code есть кнопка "restart", которая перезапускает именно jupyter notebook и очищает все текущие переменные.
Это помогает, но все-равно не совсем понятно почему просто при повторном импорте изменения в файле не учитываются.